# Mailgun Flanker email validation not working

Tags: mailgun

Hi I want to validate the email address, i find the mailgun flanker email validation python library but it's not working.

```
>>> from flanker.addresslib import address
>>>
>>> address.validate_address('foo@mailgun.com')
None
```

Please help me!

Thanks

Comment: Did you find solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use mailgun api validor,for example.

```
def get_validate():
return requests.get(
    "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/address/validate",
    auth=("api", "pubkey-5ogiflzbnjrljiky49qxsiozqef5jxp7"),
    params={"address": "foo@mailgun.net"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example: https://github.com/diegovalle/crimenmexico/blob/master/api/forms.py

view.py:

```
def get_validate(email):
    return requests.get(
            "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/address/validate",
            auth=("api", "pubkey-f387c7feae844803cdda9c99d4b976cb"),
            params={'address': email})


rq = get_validate(email)
if rq is not None:
    data_email = rq.json()
    if data_email['is_valid'] == False:
        if data_email['did_you_mean'] is not None:
            print("Error, Wrong Email")
        else:
            print("Error, Wrong Email")
    else:
        print("Ok, Email Correct")
```